# How can I add a Back arrow to a tool bar?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have an 'info' button that does a modal flip to an info page. I want a navigation type back arrow at the top to flip back.
None of the bar buttons look like Back buttons/arrows.

I've tried adding a navigation bar, but that won't show the Back as its the top level.

How can I achieve this? Or what methods do others use for returning from an info page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you go system way and use "Done" button on a right side of `UIToolbar`? It's how native "Weather" and "Stocks" apps do on iOS. Check out "Done" button in Interface Builder (set both Style and Identifier to "Done").

If you really want to achieve that "Back" button, you'll have to create a custom button with images resembling native "Back" button.

Comment: Thanks. The Weather and Stocks apps use DONE because the page has settings on it. It's seems strange to use 'DONE' when theres nothing to do, just info about the app.
Maybe i'll just leave it as Done anyway just for simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a `UIBarButtonItem` with a custom view to make an effect like this. Take a look at this question and answer: [How to add custom image in navigation bar button item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5933800/how-to-add-custom-image-in-navigation-bar-button-item)