# Double navigation bar objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

Double navigation bar image
 [image]

Guys, i'm pushing from a view, that not support segue, programmatically using the code:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
OtherUsersProfileViewController * vc=[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"OtherUsersProfileViewController"];
vc.agent_ID = self.opponentID;
vc.agent_Name = self.title;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

And in OtherUsersProfile im getting a double navigation bar, what can it be?

Comment: have you crated a custom navigation bar view is storyboard?

Comment: Yes i do.......

Comment: see my answer may be it helps

Answer (score 1):

As from [Image](https://%20i.stack.imgur.com/W9mhR.png) You don't need to add New Navigation in storyboard.

You have to option to achieve this :

> First Way: Using Default Navigation Bar

1. Just Remove default back button and add your new Custom Navigation Button.

   [Hide Back Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/614212/how-to-hide-back-button-on-navigation-bar-on-iphone)

   [Add Custom Image in Nav Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5933800/how-to-add-custom-image-in-navigation-bar-button-item)

> Second Way : Remove Default Navigation bar and add your Custom Nav bar Via Story board.

```
 self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
 //And then your code will work fine.
```